# Resize artboard to content in Sketch

Tags: artboard, sketch-app

Does the Sketch app provide something like a "resize artboard to content" command? If yes, where can I find it?

Comment: the question looks like offtopic, but anyway what the version on the Sketch do you use? in last versions  there is a command for fitting the artboard to artwork

Comment: Where should I have posted the question then? ^^

Comment: Cool, where can I find the command. I'm using the latest version (3.0.1)

Comment: Have no access right now, try "Trim Transparent Pixels"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has not been accepted and I think what OP were looking for is resize the artboard to fit to the content with it, and thus it got no answer so far.

While I don't know when this feature had been available, but in Sketch 3.7, you can achieve it exactly. Just select the artboard and on the Inspector, click on the `Resize to Fit`. Sketch automatically resize the artboard to fit to the content.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, the 'Resize to Fit' button (pictured above, in the properties pane when the Artboard tool is active) is always greyed out for me, but I can instead do `Layer > Resize Artboard to Fit`

Answer (score 5):

1. Select the content around which you want to make an artboard.
2. Click on the artboard button (or) go to Insert → Artboard.
3. On the right you will see various artboard sizes. The top one will be called "around selection".

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign and thanks for the contribution!  This question is not asking *how to create* an artboard, but rather *how to resize one*

Answer (score 3):

FYI, my suggestion is an extension to Jagrat Jagz Desai's method. It's not fully automated but does save you the step of checking the size of your content in order to create an artboard at that exact size.

1. in the *Layers List* on screen left, select the artboard that
   corresponds to your content
2. delete artboard and hit 'Keep Layers' button when prompted
3. highlight content, then insert new artboard (A)
4. select 'Around Selection' option in the *Inspector* on screen right

Comment: Unfortunately, this really is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'Edit → Scale' command to resize artboards.

Comment: Have you tried it? in Sketch 3. Select artboard -> Edit -> Scale to resize

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me when I want to resize/scale down the size of an existing artboard.

Answer (score 1):

Click the art-board layer on the left, there in the right panel you will see the size of an art-board, just readjust according to your need.

Comment: Hi Shrés, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Having not previously found a good solution to this problem, I went and built a plugin to do just that.

http://zhifengkoh.github.io/resize_artboard/

**Summary of features**

- Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> resizes the parent artboard of your currently selected layer. You can also resize one or more selected artboards (or the parent artboards of one or more selected child layers) all at once.
- Resize all the artboards on the current page with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. However, if you have a very large Sketch file with tons of artboards on the page, I'm not sure what kind of performance impact that'll have.
- The relative positioning of all layers on the artboard is always preserved
- The positioning of the artboard's layers with respect to the artboard's top-left corner will only consider visible layers. That means if a hidden layer is sticking out to the left of the visible layers, when you resize the artboard it will stick out the left side of the artboard's X axis.
- The artboard itself is never moved relative to other artboards on the page

Let me know (preferably on Github) if you have any comments or feedback!